# Why don't I see little green exit icons for unwind segues in xCode?

Tags: ios

I am following Apple's [Your Second App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/SecondiOSAppTutorial.pdf) tutorial. On page 75 of the pdf version, it says in step #3 to control drag from the Cancel button to the unwind segue's destination proxy object in the scene dock. I don't see a green exit icon (for the unwind segue) in the scene dock. (See screenshot below). I know that unwind segues are a new-ish feature of xcode. I am using "Version 4.4.1 (4F1003)." Is it possible my version does not support unwind segues? Alternately, the tutorial had me implement certain methods in the master view controller that "advertise" it as a destination for unwind segues. If I did something wrong in that part of the tutorial, maybe the green unwind segue icon would not show?

What steps can I take to debug this?

[image]

Comment: Just create that poor button programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need at least Xcode 4.5 that is available for free in the Mac App Store. The latest version of Xcode includes the iOS6 SDK and of course: unwind segues (iOS6 feature).

Comment: Well thats nice. And i wasted half an hour for that... Ffs... XCode 4.3.2 :)